# Outlook message body only return the most recent message

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I know using the Office JavaScript API I can retrieve the body of selected message.

```
 var _item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
 var body = _item.body;
    // Get the body asynchronous as text
    body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            //access the message body here
        }
        else {
            $('#subject').html(asyncResult.value.trim());
        }
    });
```

However, in those cases where I have a series of messages going back and forth(i.e. I ask one question and got answered and ask another and got answered again) I only want to retrieve the most recent one or the most recent two messages. What would be the best way to do this? Office.js does not seem to support this naively.

I am thinking using Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be by using [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mail_api_overview#common-use-cases).